# Static button placement vs dynamic placement?

Tags: forms, mobile, buttons

I have a form flow I'm working on where there is one question per step. Is it better to have the "next" button always positioned in the same spot at the bottom of the mobile screen, or to move it dynamically depending on where the question/prompt ends on the screen?

thank you!

Comment: Do most of your questions fit on a single screen? What kind of input are you requesting from the user? Just checkboxes/radio buttons (and other tap-only responses), or keyboard input also?

Comment: @maxathousand Even though it is prolonging the steps (clocking in at about 12 now) I am sticking with one per page, but the complexity of them changes. Sometimes its writing text in boxs, some are drop down, and then there are pages where their business name is asked, and needs to allocate space for multiple locations. I inherited this design from their dev team and am getting a lot of pushback.

Comment: Would you be able to provide screenshot/mockup of the UI?

Answer (score 2):

> move it dynamically depending on where the question/prompt ends on the screen

I wouldn't necessarily move the button with the size of the question. It is very natural to have the button within an easy reach of the thumb. BUT I would not have it statically shown in the bottom, since then it would be hidden by the keyboard and would require an extra click (and possibly confusion) from the user.
My solution would be to have the button in the bottom of the view (and above the keyboard when shown). So a combination of your two suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I know we talk about platform agnostic design, but it's not really true. Touch-screen and reach are an integral part of the usability of a mobile device application.

The reason this is important is because, keeping a 'Next' button in view is important, but making access to that button as easy as possible is equally so.

This may come down to aesthetics, so if your application is solely web based, having it based at the bottom of the content may be the right place for it, if you're catering for a mobile application, most certainly locking it to the bottom, and within the reach of thumbs, might be the better choice for those platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find a good reason to have a min-height for the form (the button is anyway on the bottom of the form), but you can use a floating button on mobile, if it is a CTA and the most important button on the screen (no matter if the form has a small or big height).

[image]

Comment: Having a floating button might obscure parts of the form itself. It might be worth it to find a solution that address also those edge cases.